# faster input output of floating numbers in c

Tags: c, io

For faster integer input in c we can use http://abhisharlives.blogspot.in/2012/06/really-fast-io-methods-for-programming.html methods ,but how to take faster input of floating numbers in c?

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: In many coding competition data given is floating number.

Comment: Can you read it in binary?  It is a lot faster than parsing the textual form using scanf.

Comment: You should not care. Disk IO (even with SSD) is a *lot* slower than input and output routines

Answer (score 1):

Using ideas from the link you provided, I wrote up my own fast floating number input technique. Here's the code (including the `main()` to test it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define gc getchar_unlocked

int neg;

int scandigits(double *x, int div) {
  register int c = gc();
  register double pow10 = 1;
  if ( x == NULL ) {
    return -1;
  }
  *x = 0;
  while ( (c < '0' || c > '9') && c != '-' ) {
    c = gc();
  }
  if ( c == '-' ) {
    neg = 1;
    c = gc();
  }
  while ( !(c < '0' || c > '9') ) {
    *x *= 10;
    *x += (c - '0');
    pow10 *= 10;
    c = gc();
  }
  if ( neg )
    *x = -*x;
  if ( div )
    *x /= pow10;
  return c;
}

void scandouble(double *x) {
  double left, right = 0;
  if ( x == NULL ) {
    return;
  }
  neg = 0;
  int ret = scandigits(&left, 0);
  if ( ret == '.' )
    scandigits(&right, 1);
  *x = left + right;
}

int main() {
  double d;
  scandouble(&d);
  printf("%f", d);
  return 0;
}
```

**Note:** In general, most competitive coding contests do NOT require fast IO. Instead, they require much better algorithms etc. However, in some *very* rare cases you require fast IO to eke out that last 0.01s to make your code get accepted. I would suggest using such trickery (that's what I call it) in only such cases.

Comment: Did some testing: Gets the sign wrong when `-` precedes `.` like `-0.001286`.  Other than that works like `atof()` about 52% of the time.  When it differs, error is about the 3 bits of precision.  Worst case, about 5 bits. (of of 53).  Of course, does not handle exponential notation, INF, NAN. TBD on `-0.0` and sub-normals.  Fails with numbers near `DBL_MAX`.

Comment: Corrected for the sign problem. The problem existed for numbers in the range open interval (-1.0, 0.0).
Since the code is meant for competitive coding (which has very fixed format input and no need for real error checking), there is no need to handle exponential notation, INF, NAN etc.

Answer (score 0):

Often using integer math is faster than `double`.  The below uses integer math to compose the significand and optional exponent.

```
double getdouble(void) {
  int ch = getchar();
  int sign = ch;
  if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') {
    ch = getchar();
  }
  long long sum = 0;
  int digit_count = 0;
  int dp_offset = -1;
  int power10 = 0;
  int dp = '.';
  for (;;) {
    while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
      digit_count++;
      if (sum < LLONG_MAX / 10) {
        sum = sum * 10 + ch - '0';
      } else {
        power10++;
      }
      ch = getchar();
    }
    if (ch == dp) {
      dp = '0';
      dp_offset = digit_count;
      ch = getchar();
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (dp_offset >= 0) {
    power10 -= digit_count - dp_offset;
  }
  if (ch == 'e' || ch == 'E') {
    ch = getchar();
    int esign = ch;
    if (esign == '-' || esign == '+') {
      ch = getchar();
    }
    int expo = 0;
    while (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
      expo = expo * 10 + ch - '0';
      ch = getchar();
    }
    if (esign == '-') expo = -expo;
    power10 += expo;
  }
  double y = sum;
  if (power10) {
    // combine these 2 steps for speed with `pow(10,power10)`.
    // leave separate for better handling of very large/very tiny numbers 
    y *= pow(5, power10);  // 
    y = ldexp(y, power10);
  }
  if (sign == '-') y = -y;
  return y;
}
```

Same answer as `atof()` 86% of the time.
When in error, 1 bit error.
Worse case: 1 bit.
**Handles exponential notation** and sub-normals, -0.0.
Does not handle  NAN, INF.
Returns INF on `+/-DBL_MAX`, works on all smaller values.